# Who or what sent the prophetic dreams to Faramir and Boromir?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

In *The Fellowship of the Ring* both Faramir and Boromir have prophetic dreams urging them to seek Imladris (Rivendell) :

> [O]n the eve of the sudden assault a dream came to my brother in a troubled sleep; and afterwards a like dream came oft to him again, and once to me.
>
> 'In that dream I thought the eastern sky grew dark, but out of the west a light shone forth, and from that light a voice called out, saying:
>
> Seek for the Sword that was broken;
> In Imladris it dwells.
> There shall be taken counsels
> Stronger than Morgul-spells.
> There shall be shown a token
> That Doom is near at hand.
> For Isildur's Bane shall waken,
> And the Halfling forth shall stand.

Who or what is the genesis of this message?

*Note* : Tolkien has stated that some things in his Legendarium are a mystery, even to him. This might be one of those cases.

Comment: I've thought that it might be Eru Iluvatar, however I believe his interventions, if there have been any at all, are less direct. For example, Bilbo stumbling across the ring rather than a random Orc or some other creature is hinted at being possibly the interaction of some other power.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Tolkien never clarified the point

Although I should be fair here; the first draft of Boromir's dream is lost, having been written on a page that was later misplaced, as Christopher Tolkien notes:

> The verse (if it was already a verse) that brought Boromir to Rivendell is lost in its earliest form with the lost page
>
> <sup>*History of Middle-earth* VII *The Treason of Isengard* Chapter VI: "The Council of Elrond (1)"</sup>

None of the subsequent drafts, nor any of Christopher Tolkien's notes, discuss the origin of the dream. Nor have I found anything in *Letters* to clarify his intentions here.

It's most commonly believed that the visions were sent either by Eru Ilúvatar or by the Valar; this is the opinion held by Thomas Shippey, a prominent Tolkien scholar, who wrote in [*The Road to Middle-earth*](https://www.amazon.ca/Road-Middle-earth-Revised-Expanded/dp/0618257608) (as reported in *Reader's Companion*):

> > In Middle-earth, one may say, [Providence](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/providence) or the Valar sent the dream that took Boromir to Rivendell. But they sent it first and most often to Faramir, who would no doubt have been a better choice.
>
> <sup>*The Lord of the Rings: A Reader's Companion* Book II Chapter 2: "The Council of Elrond"</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. Marked as answered, +1.